# How is iOS development in Xcode adherent to MVC architecture?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

I am new to iOS development and am trying to figure out how it is MVC.

I see how there are controllers that produce views.

However, where are the models that represent data? I just see iOS development as controllers that "delegate" (I still don't see what that çlearly means.) functionality to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS development done the right way is a great example of true MVC programming.  If you really want to see this in action, check out Stanford's iTunes U videos.

The model for iOS will be either a CoreData store, a manually built class, etc.  The ViewController is the controller and the View will be the nib or storyboard scene that contains the UI elements and is wired up to the VC.

Answer (score 0):

There is a summary of MVC in the [Core Competencies Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1)

And there is a more detailed description in the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14)

Simply put - MVC in Cocoa means that views don't get their data directly from the model objects, and model objects don't update their state directly from the views. There is always a controller in the middle that is mediating the communication.

Answer (score -1):

In simply words you create views and code separately. Then you link them between themselves using class name, variables and methods. Likewise for program data.

But it is too basic question. You can learn it from the first pages of all the books about objective-c